# delete cookie from other domain

Tags: java, cookies, single-sign-on

I'm creating SingleSignOn system and I have one big question.

Lets say that I have 3 domains - *domain1*, *domain2* and *domain3*

I'm logged in all of those domains.

I want to logout in *domain3* and then automatically be logged out in *domain1* and *domain2*.

Is it possible to delete some cookies in *domain1* and *domain2* when I am in *domain3*?

The solution is to redirect from one domain to another, but it's ugly solution, and I would like to do this clearly.

Maybe you have some ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you using to manage cookies?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot delete cookie.
Approach for Single Sign Out: SingleSignOn system must remember logged users and applications where user is logged, when user logs out (or ticket/session expire) SingleSignOn system has to call logout URL on all aplications where user was logged. This approach is implemented in [Central Authentication Service](http://www.jasig.org/cas).

Answer (score 0):

This is a single sign out or single logout problem. Generally, you can't delete cookies from domains other than the one that the user is currently visiting (otherwise you could manipulate Facebook cookies for example). That said, I'm assuming you have some control over these domains, so you do have a few options:

## Client side Options

If the domains are subdomains of the same root domain e.g.

- billing.example.com
- crm.example.com
- reports.example.com

You could scope the cookie to be attached to the .example.com domain.

If this is not possible (because they're customer domains) but you have a list of them, you could have the logout process call each of the applications in turn (either a logout pixel, logout ajax etc. depending on what you can put on the other domains). This is not a secure solution but is better than no single logout.

## Server side Options

The ways to do it server side is to:

Have the logout on any one of the domains invalidate it's cookie and then either redirect or call back to a central single sign on server to let it know that the user has logged out. Then, either have the single sign on server make a call out to all of the domains that a user has logged into and ask them to log that user out or have the domains poll back to the single sign on server on a regular basis to check whether single sign on sessions have expired.

See any of the following for more information:

- [CAS single sign out](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Single+Sign+Out)
- [Federation Lab single logout](https://fed-lab.org/best-practises/single-logout/)